# Is a MySQL Foreign Key without a constraint simply an int?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I know everyone is going to jump in and say "No!" - but can you do a bit better and explain why.

**Why am I asking this?**

I'm finding myself working with a lot of legacy SQL (using Django) where tables are set up in a traditional way.

Parent table

```
id  name
0   ParentA
1   ParentB
```

Child table

```
id parent_id name
0    0       ChildA0
1    0       ChildA1
2    1       ChildB1
```

Now because of the nature of my work (I'm simply using the data and not modifying it) and I am often times wondering instead of doing this..

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

To this..

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, db_column ='parent')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

It would certainly make my life easier??  And if it's just an integer I would think go for it..  But I want to ask the experts first.

FYI:  The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Parent` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `pmVariants` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **no**

A foreign key in MySQL can be anything: an `int` a `string` whatever.
It is smart to keep your keys as short a possible, so an integer is a logical and fast choice.

A word of advice: **never use a `unique key` if you can use a `primary key` (PK) instead**.
They may look the same to you, but they are not the same to the DB.
If a table has no PK, MySQL will create a hidden integer auto_increment PK instead.
This is very wasteful and disables lots of optimizations, esp on InnoDB.

Comment: Hey I didn't know that - thanks a lot!  That said if it is an int can I refer to it as a ForeignKey in Django?  Great answer!

Comment: +1, however only InnoDB will create a hidden PK. MyISAM handles PK in a different (worse) way. What's wasteful is using extra space (6 bytes vs 4 bytes assuming that the general practice is using 4 byte integers). It doesn't seem like a lot of space unless there are billions of records where it really does contribute to waste of space. Excellent answer however.

Comment: @N.B. I didn't want to go into **that** much detail, but InnoDB includes the PK on every index, so you will get an extra 4 bytes on the table+an extra 4 bytes on the index + and extra 4 bytes for an index you don't need. That's 12 bytes per row. The performance hurt is even worse.